# SysRq key on a TLC keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, magic-sysrq

I have a "Logitech G14 TKL SE" keyboard. In this keyboard, the print screen key is emulated with the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> keys combination.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to get the <kbd>SysRq</kbd> magic key functionality.

- I enabled it with:

  ```shell
  sudo sysctl kernel.sysrq=1
  ```
- If a do:

  ```shell
  cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
  ```

  I get the expect `1` as the result.
- If I look at journal with:

  ```shell
  journalctl -f
  ```

  I'm expecting to get something like this if the key combination is right:

  ```
  kernel: sysrq: HELP :
  ```

  But it doesn't appear.

The operating system is Ubuntu 22.04.

I tried different combinations with <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>Ins</kbd>, all without success, just some undesired screen shots. Probably the issue here is with the keyboard. Any suggestions?